# Word for "All of these things"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What's a word that means "all of these things" or "all of these things together" ?

In the context of it leading up to something or an outcome. For example:

> **All of these things** lead to me eating french fries.

What's one word or a couple of fancier words that would sum up "all of these things".

Sorry if that is confusing.

Comment: You could say "*Taken together*, these things lead to me eating french fries." or "As a group,..." or "All in all, ..."

Comment: _Totality,_ perhaps; or _In sum, these things led to my eating fries..._ Welcome to ELL, and thanks for your question, but it is very hard to understand what you need. If you tell us what research you have done on your own, it might be easier for us to help you. Here is a [**link**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) specifically about how to ask a useful question.

Answer (score 1):

**[altogether](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/altogether)** means "considering everything".

**Altogether**, these things lead to me eating french fries.

**[all told](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20told)** means "with everything or everyone taken into account"

**All told**, these things lead to me eating french fries.

**Altogether** is very widely used, but it is difficult to say how many instances relate to this meaning. Here is a real example of the usage of **all told**:

> **All told**, it is fair to say that charter initiatives tend to be more effective when developed and implemented as part of a broader programme of change.   [Empowering the customer](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=oO0O5_5zK0kC&pg=PA30&dq=%22all%20told%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ16WrpJbPAhWDOBQKHep_Cwc4PBDoAQgpMAM#v=onepage&q=%22all%20told%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

You could also say "all of the above" instead of saying "all of these things".
Example: *All of the above* mean that another decision should be taken regarding this matter.

Comment: Please add references to your answer.